# Error while declaring/deploying a contract on Starknet by using starkli

Tags: starknet, cairo-lang

I'm trying to declare my first contract on Starknet by following the [official Starknet tutorial](https://book.starknet.io/chapter_2/index.html).

The problem is that when I try to declare my contract with this command:

`starkli declare path/to/contract.sierra --compiler-version=2.0.1`

after having set the environment variables `STARKNET_ACCOUNT` and `STARKNET_KEYSTORE`

I get the error:

`Error: expected ',' or '}' at line 11 column 3`

I don't know what file does this error refer to, but I'm assuming it is not my contract, since the same error appears even when I try to **deploy** the contract [already declared in the tutorial](https://book.starknet.io/chapter_2/deploy_call_invoke.html#contract_deployment) with:

`starkli deploy <class hash> ...`

I'm using Ubuntu and a Python 3.9 virtual environment. For the rest I followed the tutorial step by step. If you need more info I'll provide it as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message "Error: expected ',' or '}' at line 11 column 3" indicates an issue with the file **`path/to/contract.sierra`** that you're attempting to deploy. In the newer versions of Starkli, it's necessary to use a JSON file, specifically **`path/to/contract.sierra.json`**. If you're using Scarb to compile your contract, you'll likely find the JSON file at **`target/dev/starknetbook_chapter_2_Vote.sierra.json`**.

Therefore, your declare command should be formatted as follows:

```
starkli declare target/dev/starknetbook_chapter_2_Vote.sierra.json --rpc <RPC-BEING-USED> --account <PATH-TO-ACCOUNT-DESCRIPTION> --keystore <PATH-TO-SIGNER-JSON>
```

Please note that The Starknet Book has been updated to include these modifications. For more details, visit the following link: https://book.starknet.io/chapter_2/deploy_call_invoke.html#contract_deployment

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer. I ended up not using starkli, but just the raw Starknet CLI, since it was ok for such a small project as the one I was doing. I hope your answer will be helpful for people with this same problem in the future!